# SIGABRT 'not enough frames in stack'

Tags: iphone, ios, frames, sigabrt

my app cant seem to find the selector (submitScore:) but i have already declared it

here :

```
 @interface Highscores (Private)
    - (void)loadCurrentPlayer;
    - (void)loadHighscores;
    - (void)updateHighscores;
    - (void)saveCurrentPlayer;
    - (void)saveHighscores;
    - (void)button1Callback:(id)sender;
    - (void)button2Callback:(id)sender;
    -(void)button3Callback:(id)sender;
    -(void)submitScore:(id)sender;
    -(void)viewBoard:(id)sender
@end
```

then it is called in here:

```
    UIButton *mybutton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    mybutton1.frame=CGRectMake(80, 50, 150, 40);
    [mybutton1 setTitle:@"Submit Score" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(submitScore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIButton *mybutton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    mybutton2.frame=CGRectMake(80,100,150,40);
    [mybutton2 setTitle:@"View Leaderboard" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mybutton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(viewBoard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [myView addSubview:mybutton1];
    [myView addSubview:mybutton2];
    [myView release];

}

-(void)submitScore
{
    NSString *request_url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.18.8/lboard/addrank.php?did=%@&sre=%@&nme=%@&fmt=jsn",
                             currentScore, currentPlayer];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request_url]; 
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.delegate=self;
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)]; 
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

whenever i press one of those 2 buttons i get this error:

```
2011-12-22 14:27:32.462 tweejump[5381:707] -[Highscores submitScore:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x267970
2011-12-22 14:27:32.469 tweejump[5381:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Highscores submitScore:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x267970'

terminate called throwing an exceptionProgram received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

i tried the solutions on other topics like weak linking the lib but i still get that error.

**what else should i do? how can i remove the SIGABRT?**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `myButton1`'s selector to be for a method with the signature of `- (void)submitScore:(id)sender` when in actuality your method signature is `- (void)submitScore`.

Set the selector to `myButton1` to `@selector(submitScore)`.

Comment: Drop the colon from the method signature in the `@selector` when you create `myButton1`.

Comment: O_O now im getting this error `target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-191-70
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 7171]
[Switching to thread 7171]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
/Developer_2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
kill
quit`

Comment: Did you fix the issue that @Tim mentioned?

Comment: could you direct me on how can i fix that issue? this is the first time i will be encountering udid O_O

Comment: It's pretty clear. The string has 3 placeholders but you only pass in `currentScore` and `currentPlayer`. I'm assuming that you wrote this code and that you know what addrank.php is supposed to do...

Comment: i mean how can i get that udid thats the only thing i want to know.. thankss

Comment: `NSString* udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];`

Answer (score 1):

The format string is expecting three values and being given only two

```
NSString *request_url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.18.8/lboard/addrank.php?did=%@&sre=%@&nme=%@&fmt=jsn",
                         currentScore, currentPlayer];
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch, but that's not causing this particular exception.